# Freefem++ code for solving Cahn-Hilliard equations with dynamic boundary conditions

Tags: freefem++

I do not know how to solve the Cahn-Hilliard equation with dynamic boundary conditions with Freefem++4.2.1. In particular, the boundary conditions I consider are not traditional Dirichlet or Newman boundary conditions, but boundaries that satisfy some parabolic equation. Also, for an integral term like (\nbala_{\Gamma}u,\nbala_{\Gamma}v), where \Gamma is the boundary of the circular region, u and v are the test and trial functions respectively, I don't know how to solve it with Freefem++.

I have written code for dynamic boundary conditions for a circular region with holes, but have not observed the expected numerical results. So, I suspect I'm having a problem with the boundary integral term, but I'm not so sure. The following is my code, welcome to give guidance, thank you!

```
//The disk Mesh with the hole
border a1 ( t =0 ,2* pi) { x=80* cos ( t ) ; y= 80*sin ( t) ; label =1;}
border b1 ( t =0 ,2* pi) { x =20+40* cos( t ) ; y =40* sin (t ) ; label =2;}
mesh Th = buildmesh ( a1 (600) + b1 ( -400) ) ;
plot ( Th , wait =1 , ps=" Thcirclewithhole .eps") ;
//The slab Mesh with the hole
// time step: 0.02, 0.01, 0.005, 0.0025, 0.00125
real tau =0.01;                  

fespace Vh(Th, P1);

real t = 0, T = 2, NN = T / tau;
real a,b;
real la=1/2;
real A,B;
real E1,E2;
real A1,B1,C1;
real A2,B2,C2;
// define numerical solutions and finite element auxiliary functions
Vh uh,uhcf3;
Vh u1h, v1h, w1h, x1h, fh, gh;
Vh u2h, v2h, w2h, x2h;`your text`
Vh u3h, v3h, w3h, x3h;
// initial solution 
Vh u0=-0.01+0.02*randreal1();

// numerical problem
problem SolveCHdy1(u1h, w1h, v1h, x1h)= int2d(Th)(u1h * v1h / tau) - int2d(Th)(u0 * v1h / tau)
+ int2d(Th)(dx(w1h) * dx(v1h) + dy(w1h) * dy(v1h))
+ int2d(Th)(w1h * v1h) // eq 1
+ int2d(Th)(w1h * x1h) 
- int2d(Th)(dx(u1h) * dx(x1h) + dy(u1h) * dy(x1h))
- int1d(Th)(dx(u1h) * dx(x1h) + dy(u1h) * dy(x1h))
+ int1d(Th)((dx(u1h) * N.x + dy(u1h) * N.y) * (dx(x1h) * N.x + dy(x1h) * N.y))
- int2d(Th)(fh * x1h) 
- int1d(Th)(gh * x1h)
- int1d(Th)(u1h * x1h / tau) + int1d(Th)(u0 * x1h / tau);
    


// solve numerical solution
for (int i = 0; i <= NN; i++) 
{

fh =1/2*u0 ^ 3 - 1/2*u0;
//gh = u0 ;
gh=u0-7/10;


SolveCHdy1;


u0 = u1h;
t = t + tau;



plot(Th,u1h,value=1, fill=1,ps="uh_h_0.7_2.eps");

}
```